# Memory issue with Numpy memory-mapped array assignment

Tags: python, memory, numpy

In the following code:

```
@profile
def do():

    import random
    import numpy as np

    image = np.memmap('image.np', mode='w+', dtype=np.float32, shape=(10000, 10000))

    print("Before assignment")

    x = random.uniform(1000, 9000)
    y = random.uniform(1000, 9000)
    imin = int(x) - 128
    imax = int(x) + 128
    jmin = int(y) - 128
    jmax = int(y) + 128
    data = np.random.random((256,256))
    image[imin:imax, jmin:jmax] = image[imin:imax, jmin:jmax] + data

    del x, y, imin, imax, jmin, jmax, data

    print("After assignment")

do()
```

The memory used at the second print statement is increased compared to at the end of the first print statement - here's the memory_profiler output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     1                             @profile
     2                             def do():
     3    10.207 MB     0.000 MB   
     4    10.734 MB     0.527 MB       import random
     5    21.066 MB    10.332 MB       import numpy as np
     6                             
     7    21.105 MB     0.039 MB       image = np.memmap('image.np', mode='w+', dtype=np.float32, shape=(10000, 10000))
     8                             
     9    21.109 MB     0.004 MB       print("Before assignment")
    10                             
    11    21.109 MB     0.000 MB       x = random.uniform(1000, 9000)
    12    21.109 MB     0.000 MB       y = random.uniform(1000, 9000)
    13    21.109 MB     0.000 MB       imin = int(x) - 128
    14    21.109 MB     0.000 MB       imax = int(x) + 128
    15    21.113 MB     0.004 MB       jmin = int(y) - 128
    16    21.113 MB     0.000 MB       jmax = int(y) + 128
    17    21.625 MB     0.512 MB       data = np.random.random((256,256))
    18    23.574 MB     1.949 MB       image[imin:imax, jmin:jmax] = image[imin:imax, jmin:jmax] + data
    19                             
    20    23.574 MB     0.000 MB       del x, y, imin, imax, jmin, jmax, data
    21                             
    22    23.574 MB     0.000 MB       print("After assigment")
```

The RAM has increased from 21.109Mb to 23.574Mb. This is causing issues if I put that block of code in a loop:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     1                             @profile
     2                             def do():
     3    10.207 MB     0.000 MB   
     4    10.734 MB     0.527 MB       import random
     5    21.066 MB    10.332 MB       import numpy as np
     6                             
     7    21.105 MB     0.039 MB       image = np.memmap('image.np', mode='w+', dtype=np.float32, shape=(10000, 10000))
     8                             
     9    21.109 MB     0.004 MB       print("Before assignment")
    10                             
    11   292.879 MB   271.770 MB       for i in range(1000):
    12                             
    13   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           x = random.uniform(1000, 9000)
    14   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           y = random.uniform(1000, 9000)
    15   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           imin = int(x) - 128
    16   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           imax = int(x) + 128
    17   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           jmin = int(y) - 128
    18   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           jmax = int(y) + 128
    19   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           data = np.random.random((256,256))
    20   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           image[imin:imax, jmin:jmax] = image[imin:imax, jmin:jmax] + data
    21                             
    22   292.879 MB     0.000 MB           del x, y, imin, imax, jmin, jmax, data
    23                             
    24   292.879 MB     0.000 MB       print("After assignment")
```

and the RAM used will increase at each iteration. Is there any way to avoid this issue? Is it a Numpy bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: this is on MacOS X, and I see the issue with Python 2.7 and 3.2, with Numpy 1.6.2 and above (including dev version).

EDIT 2: I am also seeing the issue on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that numpy is writing the data to a buffer first, and only later to the file. Probably for performance reasons.

I did some tests and after your assignment line, the file `image.np` did not change. The file only changed after I deleted the object `image`, or did a `image.flush()`. If memory is paramount, you can try putting a `image.flush()` in your loop to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For optimisation reasons, the data may not be written from `np.memmap` until the destructor for `image`  is called. You can avoid this by opening `image` as copy-on-write:

```
image = np.memmap('image.np', mode='c', dtype=np.float32, shape=(10000, 10000))
```

or you could call `del image` and then re-open once in every loop - but that doesn't sound like a good idea.